# How do you deal with wall-clock times without date in Go?

Tags: datetime, go, time

I'd like to know if there is any existing package to deal with datetimes without date in Golang.

The problem is as follows. Imagine I want to store information about shifts in a company, including when this shifts start and end, I would create something like:

```golang
import "time"

type Shift struct {
    StartTime  time.Time
    FinishTime time.Time
    // More fields
}
```

The problem is, the field time.Time also stores information about the day, month and year, and that could lead to several problems at the time of comparing shifts.

Is there any alternative like civil.Date (https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/civil) but for just times instead of just dates?

Comment: `time.Time` has time _and_ date. If you use `time.Time` and you "ignore" the date part, all what's left is time. Use the same date part so the problems vanish (just make sure it's not a daylight savings day).

Comment: A time.Time is an instance in time. It seems you want to work on "clock reading" which is _not_ an instance in time but just a string. So why not use strings? If "2:30 PM" is what you are interested in use that.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is, that time.Time will be prone to bugs in a less-than / more-than comparison if you allow the user to give a date. The goal should be to have a comparable struct and for the user not to give a date in order not to mess it up.

Comment: If you obtain "wall-clock" time as a user's input, you can convert it to `time.Duration` with 0 taken to mean 00:00:00.000 on any given day (since you're ignoring days anyway). You can then easily compare those durations.

Comment: Comparing wall-clock time isn't obvious, though. Is 23:00 two hours before 01:00 or twenty-two hours after? What about midnight and noon? That's some you have to decide in your context. I doubt there exists a package that does exactly what you want, in all cases. It should be pretty simple to just implement it yourself, though.

Comment: The need for wall-clock time is not uncommon. When Java reworked their time library, they came up with LocalTime for this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to have just time and omit the other information about the day, month and year you can make use of `Format()` method. I have created a sample program for the same as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    const (
        layoutTime = "15:04:05"
    )

    fmt.Println("Date", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("Time", time.Now().Format(layoutTime))

}
```

Output:

```
Date 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
Time 23:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

`time.Duration` can be used for wall-clock time without date. Some examples:

```golang
type Shift struct {
    StartTime  time.Duration
    FinishTime time.Duration
}

func main() {
    d1, _ := time.ParseDuration("11h")  // 11:00
    d2, _ := time.ParseDuration("20h")  // 20:00
    shift := Shift{
        StartTime:  d1,
        FinishTime: d2,
    }

    // If you want to put them into specific day
    today0 := time.Now().UTC().Truncate(24 * time.Hour)

    start := today0.Add(shift.StartTime)
    finish := today0.Add(shift.FinishTime)

    fmt.Printf("Start at: %v\nFinish at: %v\n", start, finish)
}
```

For times that span two days:

```golang
d1, _ := time.ParseDuration("-30m")   // 23:30 of previous day
d2, _ := time.ParseDuration("6h30m")  // 6:30 of next day
```

Answer (score 2):

Trust me, You still need the Date, not just the Clock.

For example : what if the `StartTime = 23:00:00` and `FinishTime = 06:00:00`, if you didn't capture the date, the information inside of the `Shift` struct is `FinishTime < StartTime`, and that goes against the words of `start` and `finish` itself.

That's where the date works, so if the `FinishTime` is more than the `StartTime`, the `StartTime` needs to be reduced by 1 day OR `FinishTime` plus 1 day.

Here's the example solution code that I make to check if the `currentTime` is between 2 time(clock)

First of all since I just need the clock information (HH:mm:ss), I prefer to use a `string` type for the `StartTime` and `FinishTime`.

```golang
type Shift struct {
    StartTime  string
    FinishTime string
}
```

and here's what it goes.

```golang
type Shift struct {
    StartTime  string
    FinishTime string
}

func main() {
    myShift := Shift{
        StartTime:  "23:00",
        FinishTime: "06:00",
    }
    actualStartTime, actualEndTIme := convertShiftClockToShiftTime(myShift.StartTime, myShift.FinishTime)
    fmt.Println(actualStartTime, actualEndTIme)
}

func convertShiftClockToShiftTime(StartTime string, FinishTime string) (startTime time.Time, endTime time.Time) {

    // I need to convert the time to a string so I can easily add the clock
    timeLayout := "2006-01-02T15:04"
    dateOnlyLayout := "2006-01-02"

    currentTime := time.Now()
    currentDate := currentTime.Format(dateOnlyLayout)
    // currentDate = Y-m-d

    startDateStr := currentDate + "T" + StartTime
    startTime, _ = time.Parse(timeLayout, startDateStr)

    endDateStr := currentDate + "T" + FinishTime
    endTime, _ = time.Parse(timeLayout, endDateStr)

    if startTime.After(endTime) {
        // plus 1 day to the endTime if the endTime < startTime
        endTime = endTime.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
    }

    return startTime, endTime
}
```

I created a function called `convertShiftClockToShiftTime` to change the clock into actual time as I mentioned before, what if the `StartTime = 23:00` and `EndTime = 06:00`.

Basically the program should know if the StartTime is more than FinishTime, FinishTime should be tomorrow.

Hope this helps, I hope my explanation can explain to you what `time` itself means.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to answer this question, as you haven't really described what the type would need to do, other than this:

> Yeah, but the point is, that time.Time will be prone to bugs in a less-than /
> more-than comparison if you allow the user to give a date. The goal should be
> to have a comparable struct and for the user not to give a date in order not
> to mess it up.

So going off that, you could use something like this:

```
package wall
import "errors"

type Clock struct { hour, minute, second int }

func NewClock(h, m, s int) (*Clock, error) {
   if h > 23 || m > 59 || s > 59 {
      return nil, errors.New("invalid input")
   }
   return &Clock{h, m, s}, nil
}

func (c Clock) Seconds() int {
   return c.hour * 60 * 60 + c.minute * 60 + c.second
}

func (c Clock) LessThan(d *Clock) bool {
   return c.Seconds() < d.Seconds()
}
```

Example:

```
package main
import "wall"

func main() {
   c, err := wall.NewClock(9, 59, 59)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   d, err := wall.NewClock(10, 59, 59)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   println(c.LessThan(d))
}
```