# Time storing issue

Tags: postgresql, go

I have to store time, like 11:30, in database. I use Postgres and "time without time zone" type. And I have a trouble with testing in Golang. I store source time like

```
sourceTime, err := time.Parse("15:04", "11:30")
```

and write it in database, but from database I get 2000-1-1 11:30. I have to compare that to time.

```
require.Equal(t, sourceTime, sqlTime )
```

It seems that Postgres store not only time, but date as well. And what should I do to pass my tests?

Now I just reset a date after every SQL request. Like this:

```
sqlTime = time.Date(0, 0, 0, sqlTime .Hour(), sqlTime .Minute(), sqlTime .Second(), 0, time.UTC)
```

I use postgres type time, as i wrote above. Here is table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders
(
......
    start_order  time  not null,
    end_order time not null,
......
    );
```

And pgAdmin displays that like "time without time zone". I read it to time.Time via common scan method, using *pgxpool.Pool

Is there a better solution?

UPD:
Found the same question here
[How do you deal with wall-clock times without date in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081142/how-do-you-deal-with-wall-clock-times-without-date-in-go)
But there are no good answers

Comment: This `2000-1-1 11:30` means you are storing in `timestamp(tz)` field not a `time` field. For the differences see [Date/time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: What postgres [data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) are you using? (this will determine what gets stored). pgx offers [types](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.3.1/pgtype#Time) to help you manage times.

Comment: exactly how do you "get" from that database? i.e . "*from database I get 2000-1-1 11:30*"

Comment: Just using select sql request and scan into time.Time

Comment: SELECT start_order, end_order  FROM orders

Comment: Postgres will store `2000-1-1 11:30` in a `time` field, that is something that is being done on the client side.

Comment: okey, i already understood that. So how i should to compare my time 11:30 and postgress time 2000-1-1 11:30? Should i override compare method?

Comment: That should have been: *Postgres will  **not** store 2000-1-1 11:30 in a time field, ...*. As example: `select '2000-1-1 11:30 '::time; 11:30:00`.

Comment: probably it's pgx driver issue

Comment: Looks like its a [deliberate choice](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/f59e8bf5551f403e6b7ec0912097bce85ea21351/pgtype/builtin_wrappers.go#L485) in PGX (no comment explaining why so I will not guess!). If you don't want this then use [Time](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.3.1/pgtype#Time).